# What is the alternative for user_check_password in drupal 8

Tags: users, 8

What is the alternative for user_check_password(), How I can verify a plane password with a user account?

Answer (score 1):

```
$uid = \Drupal::service('user.auth')->authenticate('testusername', 'testpassword');

if ($uid) {
// do stuff
 }
```